# Jenkins : Selenium GUI tests are not visible on Windows 7

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

When I run my selenium test (mvn test) from jenkins (windows) I see only the console output. I don't see the real browsers getting opened. How can I configure jenkins so that I can see the browsers running the test?

Comment: Where are the tests getting run? On the server? On VMs? Have you logged in there? Are you running headless or ?

Comment: i am run the test scripts on the jenkins using local host ,

Comment: When you log into the Jenkins server, do you see the browsers launching and running tests?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mis-understanding the reason you would use Jenkins, i believe it's designed to do exactly what it is doing, you need to install a different test-framework along with Maven and Selenium.

> Jenkins is an open source DevOps tool which is basically use to automate repetitive tasks like code deployment on *server*.

**SERVER** being the main operating word here, you are trying to run your automation scripts from your desktop.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peDWh9q_d0s

Above is a video tutorial of how to setup Maven and a very popular automation test framework, testNG.

Give me a shout if you need any more from me,

All the best,
Jack

Comment: Thanks for your dedication i am successfully building the project using maven , when i am trying to build the project using jenkins then build successfully but browser is not opened can u help me ?